# Where should the benchmarks be put in a Java (Maven) project?

Tags: java, maven, benchmarking, project-structure

I have some benchmarks that I would like to keep in the projects because I may modify them and use them again in the future, but I haven't found anything on where to put them.
In a Maven project tests have a test directory kept separate from main, but I don't suppose there's a benchmark directory.

Am I even supposed to keep them in the project?
Is there a convention on where to put benchmarks in a Maven project?

Comment: I don't know of an established convention, but placing them in the test folder makes sense, if they test the performance of your code - just like other integration/load tests.

Comment: I would put them in the test folder. You could consider making the tests fail if performance degrades. You could also put them in a separate module.

Comment: Do not put anything you do not want in your production artifact inside the `src/main` folder.

Comment: I would suggest to make a separate module as already suggested for those benchmarks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no strict convention on where to put benchmarks in a Maven project, you can just put them in a directory that makes sense for you, I usually just keep them in a "benchmark" or "performance" directory.

If you want to keep your benchmarks separate from your main code, you can create a new Maven module within your project specifically for benchmarks.

I think keeping benchmarks in the project is a good practice, in case you need to modify or reuse them in the future, and keeping them in the project you can ensure that they are versioned and maintained along with  the codebase.

But this can be vary depends on the needs and organization of your project.